# How to separate changes of two collaborators in single Git branch

Tags: git

Two of us were working in one single branch in Git. But now for reviewing and merging the changes we have to segregate the changes of each one. Below is our situation graphically, can someone suggest what is the best option?

I was thinking of trying `git rebase -i <SHA for B>` but the renamed file stays in the latest commit. Basically I want changes done by me in a separate branch, is that possible?

```
A--------B---C--D---E---F------G ---I changed file 2
|        |   |  |   |   |
|        |   |  |   |   |
|        |   |  |   |   |-----I changed file 1
|        |   |  |   |
|        |   |  |   |------- I changed File1
|        |   |  |
|        |   |  |-----I changed FILE1 & FILE2
|        |   |
|        |   |
|        |   |--------He changed FILE1 & FILE2
|        |   
|        |--------He Renamed file SSSS to XXX
|
|--- I changed FILE1
```

Comment: Do you want to split the commit history? Or just the commits that are made from now on

Comment: @TimCastelijns I want to split the commit history if possible. If its not possible then I want only my changes and remove my colleague's changes.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason the renamed file stayed is that you want to pass the *parent* of B, not B itself, to `git rebase` (i.e.`git rebase -i <SHA for A>`) if you want the changes to start with commit B. Make sure to create a new branch first via `git checkout G -b bob-branch` first (assuming your name is Bob). Then do a `git checkout G -b alex-branch` (assuming the other person's name is Alex), and do (i.e.`git rebase -i <SHA for A's parent>`). Then you will have `branch-alex` and `branch-bob` nicely split out with their respective commits.

Comment: Thank you for reply David, I will try tomorrow and let you know.